# Celery run periodic task manually

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I have a celery tasks

Part 1

```
import time
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(minutes=60), softtimelimit=timedelta(minutes=60).total_seconds())
def main():
    time.sleep(30)
```

Part 2

```
import time
@celery.task
def main():
    time.sleep(30)
```

As per usual in running celery tasks in part 2. I logged in to my python kernel and ran

```
main.delay()
```

However, for part 1, the same piece of code `main.delay()` resulted in an exception.

`ValueError: Array member at index 0, 3600.0, is of an unsupported type`

Anyways i can run this periodic task on demand as i need to debug it.

I am using celery 4.4.1

Comment: `softtimelimit=(minutes=60).total_seconds()` is this just typo? I changed it to ``softtimelimit=timedelta(minutes=60).total_seconds()`` and it worked with my Celery 4.4.1.

Comment: Yup its a typo.

Sorry what worked?